# Plotting a large data set while filtering for a year that is not a variable in that data set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Really easy question from a starting python programmer, but I am have been fighting this for two days now.

I want to plot life expectancy vs gdp in a scatter plot. This comes from a huge 60000 row data set containing the years 1950 until 2018. For this specific scatterplot I am only interested in 2018. How do I filter the df for this specific task without deleting data.

As shown below the variable year is not in my scatterplot, but I would like to filter it.

This is the code I have now, I have tried everything like df.loc, etc.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('GDP_LE_2018.csv')

le = df['Life expectancy']
gdp = df['GDP per capita']
year = df['Year']
year1 = df[df['Year'] == 2018]

plt.scatter(gdp, le)

plt.show()
```

This is the data set

```
 Entity      Code  ...  Population (historical estimates)  Continent
0     Abkhazia  OWID_ABK  ...                                NaN       Asia
1  Afghanistan       AFG  ...                          7752117.0        NaN
2  Afghanistan       AFG  ...                          7840151.0        NaN
3  Afghanistan       AFG  ...                          7935996.0        NaN
4  Afghanistan       AFG  ...                          8039684.0        NaN
```

Help would be so much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('GDP_LE_2018.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df.query('Year > == 2018')
le = df['Life expectancy']
gdp = df['GDP per capita']

plt.scatter(gdp, le)

plt.show()
```

1. convert Dataframe.
2. filter(query).

Comment: Yes, of course. When you need to work in the database, it is better to convert it to a dataframe, because it is easy to manipulate (it is similar and better than Excel). The data should be taken after filtering. Your year1 filter is separate and cannot be connected. It can but you have to add additional functions.